# How to query two tables from database in one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables which are one to many (1 challenge to many entry)
I want to get the last entry for all challenges but I also want to get the title of the challenge for that last entry.

So far I have:

```
 def index
    @discovers = Challenge.all.map{|c| c.entries.last}
 end
```

How to I also add the fact I want the Challenge.title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def index
    @challenges = Challenge.all
 end
```

Then inside your view

```
<% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  <%= challenge.title %> #  will give you challenge title
  <%= challenge.entries.last %> # will give you last entry for the challnge
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid too much on page querying so I wanted to retrict this to the controller. Also I want to get the picture I store with the last entry. Will this let me do that?

Comment: lets say your picture is `entry.photo`, you just have to say `challenge.entries.last.photo` to fetch picture for particular entry